# Android Studio emulator is not showing properly

Tags: android, android-studio, null, virtual-machine, display

Since update to android 9 android virtual device are not working properly.
The touch works but display is badly scaled...
I don't have idea how to fix that.
I've been updating everything but that didn't change anything.

*also i can't install anything or use device because "apk is null" or something like that

Here is screen of the my
[AVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZK2x.png)

Comment: Did you inspect your vm settings of your emulated devices in the AVD manager? What does the field resolution say?

Answer (score 0):

do one thing update your windows graphic card in windows update.... it will work

Comment: I did not said to use new device I said update your window graphics in windows update